# How to send multiple variable from blade to controller

Tags: php, laravel, get, controller, laravel-blade

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="from" value="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}">&nbsp;
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" value="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}"> 
<a href="{{ url("/totalsales/{{  }}") }}"></a>
```

i want to send 'from' and 'to' to controller from blade. how to write that in the  tag. the necessary code is mentioned above. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="{{ URL("/totalsales/") }}">
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="from" >&nbsp;
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="to" > 
<input type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary">
```

this is the method to send data in controller
your route should be post .

Answer (score 0):

Use `form`:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url("/totalsales/{{  }}") }}">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="from" value="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}">&nbsp;
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" value="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```